# Spring application level transaction

Tags: spring, service, transactions, spring-transactions

We are using a service provide which populates some general services. Some of the services need to be done in a transaction, like below:

```
service.transferAccount()
service.changeAccountType()
service.closeAccount()
```

So we need to develop a method TransderAccount_ChangeAccount_CloseAccount() which may look something like below

TransderAccount_ChangeAccount_CloseAccount()

```
try{
service.transferAccount()
service.changeAccountType()
service.closeAccount()
}catch(All Errors){
//find which service failed and rollback until everything backs to start state

}
```

We do not have any database here. These are only services... and the transaction need to be managed at the service level.

The project is based on Spring. 
Can you please let me know what is the best approach for this usecase?

Comment: So, where are the changes stored if you don't have any database? You need a transactional resource in order to support transactions.

Comment: The service provider connects to its own database to store and update information. It provides high level services to other applications. So to transfer account we just run service.transferAccount('AccountA','AccountB',100$), without any direct access to database. 
But there are cases when we need to run a bunch of services in a transaction. Like above sample.

Comment: Then just make the calling method transactional. What's the problem? Are the three services local Spring services or remote web services?

Comment: The services are remote web services. The service provider does not know that for my usecase, the three mentioned service are going to be run as a transaction.

Comment: Then there should be one more web service that provides this 3-in-1 functionality. You can't start a transaction from a web service client.

Comment: I have read on article http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html?page=1 It tries to do some thing similar. But it was old so I thought may be new features was added to Spring core. And may be I can find better/easier ways.